# ReactNative: How to download/save remove image to photo gallery?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have the following remote url: 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Big.Buck.Bunny.-.Landscape.png

I want to download / save this image to the photo gallery (Android / iOS).

I just didn't find a merely simple example to accomplish this task in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library like *react-native-fs* to read/write files to the storage.

Here is the github page:
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs